# Error: `t1(,%di,2)' is not a valid base/index expression

Tags: assembly, x86

Below is a sample program which i am using as an example of indexed addressing mode

```
.section .data
t1:
.int 1,3
.section  .text
.globl _start
_start:
mov $0, %di
mov t1(,%di,2), %bx
mov $1,%di
mov t1(,%di,2), %cx
add %cx,%bx
movl $1,%eax
int $0x80
```

when i assemble the above code, i get below error,

```
$ as indexed-add.s -o indexed-add.o
indexed-add.s: Assembler messages:
indexed-add.s:9: Error: `t1(,%di,2)' is not a valid base/index expression
indexed-add.s:11: Error: `t1(,%di,2)' is not a valid base/index expression
```

Any ideas where i am going wrong

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık sorry i did not get you ?, what i pasted in question is my full code

Comment: mov t1(,%di,2), %bx <------ what is (--->,<----%di,2) this comma doing?

Comment: It means `mov bx, [2 * di + t1]`, the "weird comma" is because AT&T style memory operands always have the base part, even if it's empty.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık, is %di has value 0, since t1 is an array where t1[0]=1, t1[1]=2, now i want to mov the value t1[0] to %bx,

Comment: Alexey Frunze gave your answer

Comment: Couldn't you just `mov t1+0, %bx` and `mov t1+2, %cx`, by the way? The indexes are just constants anyway..

Answer (score 2):

You're requesting to assemble this instruction (intel syntax):

```
mov bx, [t1 + di * 2]
```

You cannot scale 16-bit registers (`di` in this case) like that. Only 32-bit registers can be scaled like in this instruction:

```
mov bx, [t1 + edi * 2]
```

Please refer to the official CPU documentation from Intel or AMD for valid operand encodings.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze, Thanks for the answer, In that case is there any way i can use .int , coz if use edi (which 4bytes), i can only move from 0 to n with 4 as my multiplier

Comment: I didn't understand the question.